# Tracking changes in a SQL database

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I've spent plenty of time Googling and have found possible solutions to much simpler tables.

My company uses BGInfo religiously to keep track of ~80 properties on over 200 web servers. Those fields are a mix of server stats (IP address, OSVer, HyperV host) and versions of various installed software components. A scheduled task writes this information every day all web servers to a single database (currently >300K records). We need a query (to eventually be fed into a report) to give us a time of when *something* has changed on any given web server. A sort of automated change control if you will.

Example: WebSvr_XYZ used had 2G of RAM since inception before getting additional RAM allocated a few months later. Then a year after that, it was given a new IP address.

```
Server      Time_stamp      Host    IP              RAM
-------------------------------------------------------
WebSvr_XYZ  June 1, 2016    Virt5a  192.168.10.45   2G
WebSvr_XYZ  June 2, 2016    Virt5a  192.168.10.45   2G
WebSvr_XYZ  Aug 20, 2016    Virt5a  192.168.10.45   4G
WebSvr_XYZ  Aug 21, 2016    Virt5a  192.168.10.45   4G
WebSvr_XYZ  July 18, 2017   Virt5a  192.168.20.105  4G
WebSvr_XYZ  July 19, 2017   Virt5a  192.168.20.105  4G
WebSvr_XYZ  July 20, 2017   Virt5a  192.168.20.105  4G
```

When running against `WebSvr_XYZ`, the output against over 540 records would be

```
June 1, 2016    Virt5a  192.168.10.45   2G
Aug 20, 2016    Virt5a  192.168.10.45   4G
July 18, 2017   Virt5a  192.168.20.105  4G
```

I’ve tried the select distinct against the table them Joining it against the full table, joining on all relevant columns and using a `MIN(Timestamp)` to get the first. But I either get bad timestamps or no results at all.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` as a sequence of event. After that  you can INNER JOIN back itself data of comparing previous timestamp with current timestamp

```
; with cte as
(
    select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by Server order by Time_stamp)
    from   yourtable
)
select *
from   cte c1
       inner join c2 on  c1.Server = c2.Server
                     and c1.rn = c2.rn - 1
where c1.IP  <> c2.IP
or    c1.RAM <> c2.RAM
```